# fluid (background)images to scale on page width

Tags: html, css, background-image, fluid

I have a background problem with my site.
The thought is not to use any media queries, but to set everything on a % so it will always be viewable on any device.

What my problem is that the background image does have the right css for the with but the height is determined by the content within the div.
I want the height to always be on it's max and scale proportionally.

So what I did is the following:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="home_header">
        <div class="home_header_quote">
            <img src="images/home_header_quote.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and my CSS

```
.wrapper{
max-width:1400px;   
margin:0 auto;
}

.home_header{
background:url(../images/header_home.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
max-width:1400px;
max-height:320px;
}

.home_header_quote{
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

I hope anyone can provide me with a non-JQuery solution

Answer (score 0):

Change the background size to cover.

```
.home_header{
background:url(../images/header_home.png) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
max-width:1400px;
max-height:320px;
}
```

Comment: Thnx. Also tried that but that only takes the height of the element within. The background image is larger!

Comment: then did you try `background-size: contain;`

Comment: Yes but that scales the with of the background image to het proportional height of the image within. The image within should not determine the size of the background image or div that holds the background image

Comment: Actually " I want the height to always be on it's max and scale proportionally" is exactly what `background-size: cover;` does?

Comment: Yes I absolutely agree with you. I just found out it does. The problem I seem to have is that the image I place within the div only has a 150px height. So I don't see the rest of my background image when the browser is larger than the height of the image.